# Python validate Folders are in directory and validate an integer value

Tags: python, validation, error-handling, return-value

**The goal of this Python program is to:**

1. Take in 2 Folder paths
2. Take in 1 Integer Value
3. Validate both Folders are in the directory and that the Integer value is an int

I'm using default values (Folder paths and int) as placeholders for testing but will be using CLI arguments at a later time.

**My issue and questions are:**

**def validate_folders_arg(folder):**

When both folders are present in the specified directory the program still prints "Folders cannot be found", Is this an issue with the "return None" statement? When 1 of the 2 or both folders is not in the specified directory the program should quit.

**def validate_number_arg(number1):**

This method is supposed to check an integer value was passed, if no integer value was found the program should automatically set the value to 10. Am I doing that correctly?

**Main:**

```
def main():
    test()
```

**Test method:**

```
def test():

    path1 = r"Path1"
    path2 = r"Path2"

    main_folder = validate_folders_arg(path1)
    archive_folder = validate_folders_arg(path2)
    kept_files = validate_number_arg(5)

    # if any of the inputs is not valid return None
    if main_folder is None or archive_folder is None:
        print("Folders cannot be found")
```

**Validate Folders:**

```
def validate_folders_arg(folder):
    """validates folders in working directory"""
    try:
        isDir = os.path.isdir(folder)
        print(isDir)
        # return isDir
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

**Validate int:**

```
def validate_number_arg(number1):
    input = number1
    try:
        int(input)
        it_is = True
        # return
    except ValueError:
        it_is = False
        default_value = 10
        return default_value

    print(it_is)
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
True
Folders cannot be found
```

Comment: In `validate_folders_arg()`, the `return True` statement is commented out.  Therefore this function does not return anything, which means it returns `None` by default.

Comment: I uncommented the return statement and commented out the print statement. Now when I pass an invalid folder path  "Folders cannot be found" doesn't print.

Comment: Since you uncommented the return statement, that function now returns `True` or `False`.  But you're checking for `None`.

Comment: That did the trick! I changed the `is None` to `is False` in the `test()` method. Thank you @JohnGordon. How about setting the default value to 10 for the integer check? Is that correct?